# Запретить очистку истории Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

Нужно запретить очистку истории Firefox на рабочем компьютере. По запросу именно для этого браузера найти ничего не вышло (Хотя для Хрома есть). Есть такая возможность?

Есть подозрения, что сотрудники "гуляют" по интернету. И всё бы ничего, но пытаясь скрыть это, они очищают историю, а вместе с ней — все сохранённые пароли, куки и.д. и приходится их вводить снова.

Comment: Пусти их через прозрачный прокси и его логи уже парсь.

Comment: @donRumata да пусть "лазят", лишь бы работа делалась. Только чтобы историю вместе с сохранёнными паролями не чистили.

Comment: Не понимаю чем не нравится прозрачный прокси.

Comment: @donRumata, никогда не имел дел с прокси.

Comment: Лично я не ковырял, но можно сделать чё-то типа такого: https://habr.com/sandbox/39160/